# Is there any Fedora repository with Blender that is already build with ffmpeg support

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, export, linux

By searching in web i didn't found any solution of how to install blender that is build within ffmpeg support (within H264, Matroska etc support) from one of existing Fedora repository so it will be able to auto update with all packages.

Way to use a prebuild RPM from official site is good for one time, but it's not solving a second trouble - autoupdate with all system packages.

Is there realy no repositories for Fedora with fine prebuild Blender?

Comment: Download blender directly from https://www.blender.org/download/ Fedora is way too restrictive.

Comment: @cegaton, Fedora is but there are many repos for Fedora with fine prebuild software, like RPMFusion etc. Why nobody did a repo for fine prebuild Blender yet?

Comment: It should be possible to release Blender with FFmpeg on RPMFusion, but apparently nobody bothered to do it.